# Missing XML namespace in results from List Service?

Tags: development, web-services, xml

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235139/how-to-get-this-attribute-using-linq-to-xml

I am pulling the following data from the SharePoint list service:

```
<Result ID="1,New" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode>
    <ID />
    <z:row ows_ContentTypeId="0x010090ADDB8ED990B741A07020AB204CDB880100311975766C6F0E4CBE4EBFBC3CBFD9AB" ows_Title="test 2 attachments343434" ows_AggregateDesc="&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClass05363FABD7BB400483A6AE4BB3B9B6CE&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;yes?&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" ows_Remarks="&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassB63AA0BFC1804E24B10C9559D7FBEBA5&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;no?&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" ows_PublishDate="2012-06-15 12:00:00" ows_MemoStatus="Submitted" ows_ID="6" ows_ContentType="FridayMemo" ows_Modified="2012-06-27 14:00:47" ows_Created="2012-06-27 14:00:47" ows_Author="49;#Abe Miessler" ows_Editor="49;#Abe Miessler" ows_owshiddenversion="1" ows_WorkflowVersion="1" ows__UIVersion="512" ows__UIVersionString="1.0" ows_Attachments="0" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="test 2 attachments343434" ows_LinkTitle="test 2 attachments343434" ows_LinkTitle2="test 2 attachments343434" ows_SelectTitle="6" ows_Order="600.000000000000" ows_GUID="{393F36F5-FFA8-4F6E-A12A-1107AA713F25}" ows_FileRef="6;#nc/ceo/Lists/FridayMemo/6_.000" ows_FileDirRef="6;#nc/ceo/Lists/FridayMemo" ows_Last_x0020_Modified="6;#2012-06-27 14:00:47" ows_Created_x0020_Date="6;#2012-06-27 14:00:47" ows_FSObjType="6;#0" ows_SortBehavior="6;#0" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileLeafRef="6;#6_.000" ows_UniqueId="6;#{F4C6B345-4590-4791-9384-18983132F055}" ows_ProgId="6;#" ows_ScopeId="6;#{8450C4BD-0866-40ED-A0CD-22E3105E0845}" ows__EditMenuTableStart="6_.000" ows__EditMenuTableStart2="6" ows__EditMenuTableEnd="6" ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu="6_.000" ows_LinkFilename="6_.000" ows_LinkFilename2="6_.000" ows_ServerUrl="/nc/ceo/Lists/FridayMemo/6_.000" ows_EncodedAbsUrl="http://sptestmnc.nevcounty.net/nc/ceo/Lists/FridayMemo/6_.000" ows_BaseName="6_" ows_MetaInfo="6;#" ows__Level="1" ows__IsCurrentVersion="1" ows_ItemChildCount="6;#0" ows_FolderChildCount="6;#0" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
</Result>
```

I am then trying to use linq to xml to read some of the data, but it is erroring out because there is a `z` namespace that is not defined.  Has anyone else run into this?  Can anyone suggest a work around or explain why the `z` namespace is not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the namespace was defined at the very end of the `z:row`.  Once I found that I was able to get everything to work.